# How do i get classes with jquery?

Tags: jquery

how to I get classes with jquery? I know that `$("#nameOfId")` gets id, so I assumed `$(".nameOfClass")` would get class...

The problem is that id is unique while class isnt. I've tried something like `$(".nameOfClass")[2].top()`, but this doesn't work.

Edit1:
Thanks! $(".nameOfClass").position().top worked!

Comment: you can use `$(".nameOfClass").eq(2).top()`

Comment: @ArunPJohny .top() is not a valid jquery mehtod..

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy yes... `.position().top`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [eq](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) :

```
$(".nameOfClass").eq(2)
```

Or,

```
$(".nameOfClass:eq(2)")
```

Comment: @user54987 you should use $(".nameOfClass").eq(2).position().top not $(".nameOfClass").eq(2).top()